# android using zxing library

Tags: android, zxing

I launch the zxing using an intent for scanning QR codes as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_QR_CODE);
```

But this just returns the content / format. If i insatll the zxing barcode scanner , on scanning a QR code it will determine its content like if its an URL or a contact and prompt for appropriate action like add to contact or open in browser.

How can acheive the same when i trigger it using an intent

is there a document that explains the values that will be obtained by

```
 itent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                     intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
```

i want to know different contents reurned for QR codes

Answer (score 1):

The `Intent` mechanism is there for when you want to provide some action that is different from what Barcode Scanner would provide. In this case it just sounds like you want the user to open and use Barcode Scanner.

You do that a little differently but it is also just a matter of sending the right Intent. Off the top of my head:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i tried intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
activity.startActivity(intent);   I actually have another activity from which i am launching the zxing . When i do this way, it brings the zxing but not its the same as i was doing previously. It do not show those meassages like "add to contact" after scanning. It just show a message like url found

Comment: correction : When i do this way, it brings the zxing but its the SAME as i was doing previously. It do not show those meassages like "add to contact" after scanning. It just show a message like url found

Comment: I will explain my context more. I am launching zxing for barcode scanning, in this case i want to perform my own defined actions. But when i scan a QR code i want to have the default behaviour. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Well, then you had it right the first time. You get back the contents and then do what you want with it.

Comment: thanks..But the functionality given by zxing like "add to contact" , open a url etc are very good and i dont wnat to override it. SO is there a way to directly invoke that . Hope my requirement is clear

Comment: I too would like to know how to invoke zxing's default behaviour for barcode- and qr-code-types our app doesn't want to handle itself by intent. Sean Owen, do you have any suggestions here?